# (403) Your project does not have access to this feature

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

Been following the documentation on how to insert webproperties so that i can create tracking codes dynamically. The objective is to move our analytics over in Google Analytics & automatically creating the customers website on their own google account under analytics. After what little i could find online it seems like this feature might be whitelisted. So I'm making this question to figure out weather or not this is the case. Documentation is hard to figure out, cause it doesn't tell you what fields are required, what the fields mean etc. Also seems like the documentation is outdated for the PHP library. Had to change alot of the example code class names & method names to get it "working".

Here is the code snippet that i use to test this feature out.

```
<?php
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Analytics.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Oauth2.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setClientId('xxxxx');
$client->setClientSecret('xxxxxx');
$client->setRedirectUri('xxxxxxxx');
$client->setDeveloperKey('xxxxxxx');
$client->setScopes(
    array(
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.manage.users'
    )
);

$oauth2 = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
}

if (!$client->getAccessToken()) {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

  print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";

} else {
    $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

    try {
        $user = $oauth2->userinfo->get();

        $permission = new Google_Service_Analytics_WebpropertyPermissions();
        $permission->setEffective(array('EDIT', 'VIEW'));

        $trackingObject = new Google_Service_Analytics_Webproperty();
        $trackingObject->setAccountId($user['id']);
        //$trackingObject->setDefaultProfileId($user['id']);
        $trackingObject->setId('UA-xxxxx-1');
        $trackingObject->setPermissions($permission);
        $trackingObject->setIndustryVertical('INTERNET_AND_TELECOM');
        $trackingObject->setLevel('STANDARD');
        $trackingObject->setName('xxxxxx');
        $trackingObject->setWebsiteUrl('xxxxxx');

        $analytics->management_webproperties->insert($user['id'], $trackingObject);
        $accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($user); echo '</pre>';
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($accounts); echo '</pre>';
        die();

  } catch (apiServiceException $e) {
    // Error from the API.
    print 'There was an API error : ' . $e->getCode() . ' : ' . $e->getMessage();

  } catch (Exception $e) {
    print 'There was a general error : ' . $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

The exception i get is what title contains.

Comment: Have you tried playing with the API explorer? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties/insert#try-it  You are right the documentation for PHP is out dated.  A new one is in the works.

Comment: Yeah, i followed that link you sent to help on what fields to fill out. Using their testing tool i get either a "500 Backend error" message or same as i get if i call it on my own. I'm having a felling I'm either missing a parameter or filling them out wrongly.

Comment: I had the same problem with Insert user I never got that to work.  I think this will be a case of playing with the API explorer until we find out exactly what we need to send.

Comment: have you registered xxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com as a admin level user in your google analytics?

check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944933/google-analytics-api-error-403-user-does-not-have-permission-to-access-profile

Comment: @KamranShahid That's a different error. But as i authorized using the scopes i wouldn't need to add anyone as admin. Do i? I'll test it right now to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @KamranShahid Just added the E-mail as full administrator. After testing again i still get "Your project does not have access to this feature." as return message along with 403 :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write operations are still in beta.  Before you can access this feature you need to request access to the beta.

> Write operations in the Management API (e.g. create, update, delete,
>   patch) for Web Property, View (Profile), and Goal resources is
>   currently available as a developer preview in limited beta. If you're
>   interested in using these features,  [request access to the beta](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtProfileGuide#limits).

**Update:**  It takes around 3 weeks to get approved. When you are approved you will receive an email from Google inviting you to join the beta test group.

Comment: Great !! Thanks for the update. :). Could you let me know where have they mentioned about the duration for the approval ?

Comment: I applied and got approval about 3 weeks later.  That's all I know really.  Its very quite in the beta test group tbh.  If you are in a rush you can try and post it in the google+ community a few of the devs are in there.  They may be able to help you get access sooner. but I cant promise anything https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/110103497213687093818

Comment: Oh.. Thats sad. I was wondering if could somehow email them to speed-up the process. Never mind. Thanks a lot for the answer and appreciate the follow-up.