# Create Google Analytics Goal 403 Error Message: Your project does not have access to this feature

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, http-status-code-403

I am trying to create a goal inside of a Google Analytics account. To do this, I needed to use the insert method which required me to request access to the beta api.

I requested access to the Google Analytics Beta API (twice) and I am still getting the following error:

> Google_Service_Exception in REST.php line 118:
>   {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"insufficientPermissions","message":"Your
>   project does not have access to this
>   feature."}],"code":403,"message":"Your project does not have access to
>   this feature."}}

Here's my create goal code:

```
public function createGoal( $brand, $value, $steps = null )
{
    $goal = new Google_Service_Analytics_Goal();
    $goal->setActive(TRUE);
    $goal->setType('URL_DESTINATION');
    $goal->setName('Goal conversion count.');
    $goal->setValue($value);

    $urlDestinationDetails = new Google_Service_Analytics_GoalUrlDestinationDetails();
    $urlDestinationDetails->setUrl(trim($steps[count($steps)-1]['url']));
    $urlDestinationDetails->setCaseSensitive(False);
    $urlDestinationDetails->setMatchType("BEGINS_WITH");
    $urlDestinationDetails->setFirstStepRequired(True);        

    $urlDestinationDetailsStepsArray = [];

    foreach ($steps as $step)
    {
        $urlDestinationDetailsSteps = new Google_Service_Analytics_GoalUrlDestinationDetailsSteps();
        $urlDestinationDetailsSteps->setName($step['name']);
        $urlDestinationDetailsSteps->setNumber($step['number']);
        $urlDestinationDetailsSteps->setUrl(trim($step['url']));

        array_push($urlDestinationDetailsStepsArray,$urlDestinationDetailsSteps);
    }

    $urlDestinationDetails->setSteps($urlDestinationDetailsStepsArray);

    $goal->setUrlDestinationDetails($urlDestinationDetails);

    try
    {
        $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($this->initializeAnalytics($brand,['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit']));
        var_dump($analytics);
        var_dump($goal);
        $analytics->management_goals->insert($this->accountId,$this->trackingId,$this->viewId,$goal);            
    }
    catch (apiServiceException $e)
    {
        print 'There was an Analytics API service error ' . $e->getCode() . ':' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    catch (apiException $e)
    {
        print 'There was a general API error ' . $e->getCode() . ':' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

This line here throws the error:

```
$analytics->management_goals->insert($this->accountId,$this->trackingId,$this->viewId,$goal);
```

I can do anything that doesn't involve creating goals, but as soon as i try to insert (create) a goal, it errors.

I checked the google-analytics-api group but that has been closed since 2015. I am not sure what else to do. I tried creating new keys and submitting for approval again but I am still receiving this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you need to request access to the beta @ https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/account-management#limits .

According [(403) Your project does not have access to this feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682554/403-your-project-does-not-have-access-to-this-feature) it can take up to multiple weeks (2 years ago it took 3 weeks) till you get a confirmation message. I assume you got this message?

After this I would minimize the possibilities of code and try it over https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/goals/insert#try-it

> In the Management API, the write operations (e.g., create, update,
>   delete, and patch)—for Web Property, View (Profile), and Goal
>   resources—are in limited beta. To use them, request access to the
>   beta. If you try to use the following embedded APIs explorer to call
>   the write operations, you'll get an error message because it uses its
>   own project and credential. To set up the stand-alone APIs explorer to
>   work with your project and credential to call them, see Can I use my
>   own API key and/or OAuth 2.0 client ID with the Explorer?.