# .Net Google Analitics API v3: User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile. [403]

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, google-analytics

I'm trying to implement the API following this example:
[Use Google Analytics API to show information in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306872/use-google-analytics-api-to-show-information-in-c-sharp/19299981#19299981)

I have followed all the instructions and in fact I'm successful in being authenticated. When I get the list of accounts, I actually see the correct account/profile and I see that I have ALL permissions.

```
 var path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/ServiceAccountProject-354a114cc3c1.p12");
 var email = "myemail@developer.gserviceaccount.com";


 GoogleConnector ga = new GoogleConnector(path,email );
 var accounts = ga.Service.Management.Accounts.List().Execute();
```

However, when I execute the next line to get the analytics data for that exact account that I have full permissions for, I get the error
"Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile. [403] Errors [Message[User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.] Location[ - ] Reason[insufficientPermissions] Domain[global]]"

```
 var path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/ServiceAccountProject-354a114cc3c1.p12");
 var email = "myemail@developer.gserviceaccount.com";


 GoogleConnector ga = new GoogleConnector(path,email );
 var accounts = ga.Service.Management.Accounts.List().Execute();
 var nuberOfPageViews = ga.GetAnalyticsData("ga:" + accounts.Items[0].Id, new string[] { "ga:pageviews" },
            DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), DateTime.Now).Rows[0][0];
```

Please help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944933/google-analytics-api-error-403-user-does-not-have-permission-to-access-profile

Answer (score 1):

You are using the accounts.Items[0].Id when you need to be using the View (Profile) Id.

Try using the [account explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/account-explorer/) and you can see the difference between what makes an Account Id, Property Id, and View (Profile) Id.